# Sorting an array in C# except one number

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Firstly this is my code:

```
int[] a = { 3, 2, 0, 4, -5, 8, 7, 6 };
Array.Sort(a);

for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
-5
 0
 2
 3
 4
 6
 7
 8
```

My problem is that I want to sort all the numbers like the computer already does, but except the -5. This is what I want the output to be:

```
 0
 2
 3
 4
-5
 6
 7
 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
int[] a = { 3, 2, 0, 4, -5, 8, 7, 6 };
int[] result = a.OrderBy(a=> Math.Abs(a)).ToArray();
```

Result: 0 , 2, 3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8

Comment: Thanks this is better then the other solution.

Comment: It's exactly the same as the first (updated) answer!

Comment: No, it is not (literally) exactly the same. It is ***not*** plagiarism.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

int[] sorted = new [] { 3, 2, 0, 4, -5, 8, 7, 6 }.OrderBy(Math.Abs).ToArray();
// now you can print "sorted" as array
```

It will order items by their absolute values, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: And how do I out print that in the console?

Comment: @Connor: Hint: use a `foreach` loop, or `string.Join`

Comment: The same as how you did in your question ? Also you can just use `Console.Write` to print the array i think (in Java we can, so maybe it's same in c#)

Comment: No problem x) You can check my answer to help other people to find your question faster and to mark it as solved :)

Comment: @Elikill58: In this case, the result isn't an array, so the exact same code as in the question wouldn't quite work. (You could add `ToArray` to your answer, at which point it would, of course.)